# why should i choose \$(V_L-V_C)=-80V\$,instead of \$(V_L-V_C)=+80V\$ in RLC series circuit?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, homework

If the \$|V|=100V,|V_R|=60V\$,and \$|V_L|=10V\$,then what is \$|V_C|\$?,the answer is \$|V_C|=90V\$

[image]

In my thinking,\$100=\sqrt{V_R^2+(V_L-V_C)^2}\$,because the resistance of this circuit is \$Z_{th}=R+j(X_L-X_C)\$,so \$100=\sqrt{60^2+(V_L-V_C)^2}\$,then \$(V_L-V_C)=\pm80V\$

Now if i assume \$(V_L-V_C)=+80,\$ then \$V_C=V_L-80=10-80=-70V\$,so \$|V_C|=70V\$

if i assume \$(V_L-V_C)=-80,\$ then \$V_C=V_L+80=10+80=90V\$,so \$|V_C|=90V\$

So i want to ask why should i choose \$(V_L-V_C)=-80V\$,instead of \$(V_L-V_C)=+80V\$??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the beginning,i know that \$(10+(-V_C))^2=80^2\$,and the question want us to find the \$|V_C|\$,so now i rewrite the formula above

\$(10+(-V_C))^2=80^2=>(10+(-V_C))=80\$ or \$-80\$

\$10-|V_C|=80\$ or \$-80\$,now we can get two answer for this formula

> If \$10-|V_C|=80\$

\$|V_C|=10-80=-70\$

> If \$10-|V_C|=-80\$

\$|V_C|=10+80=90\$

As we know,any value of absolute must not be negative,that is ,\$|x|\ge 0\$,so obviously \$|V_C|=10-80=-70\$ is wrong

The reason i write the formula like this

\$10-|V_C|=80\$ or \$-80\$,
The \$"-"\$,negative sign, is just the direction,so i can say the direction of \$|V_C|\$
 opposite to the inductor voltage.

Comment: No, you cannot say that the direction of \$|V_C|\$ is opposite "to the others" - it's only opposite to the inductor voltage. This answer is muddled.

Comment: oh yes!yours is more precise

Answer (score 0):

> *Why should i choose \$(V_L−V_C)=−80V\$,instead of \$(V_L−V_C)=+80V\$??*

In the bigger scheme of things it doesn't matter because you are dealing with magnitudes - the amplitudes get squared in the solution.

Regarding the point about adding the magnitudes, you should note that in all cases for a series tuned circuit (resonant or not resonant) the voltage across the capacitor is 180 degrees out of phase with the inductor voltage: -

[image]

Hence, if the net voltage across L and C together is 80 volts and there is 10 volts across L then there has to be 90 volts across C.

Picture from [here](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/accircuits/series-circuit.html).

I can see you have made an answer but it's muddled. You have to think in terms of the inductor voltage having an opposite voltage polarity compared to the capacitor. And we know that the inductor's voltage magnitude is smaller than the capacitor voltage magnitude hence we can define the inductor voltage as: -

$$V_L = k\cdot V_C$$

Where \$k\$ is a fraction. Then we can say: -

$$V_C - k\cdot V_C = 80$$

\$\color{red}{\text{The above uses the capacitor voltage as a positive reference}}\$

Therefore,  \$V_C = \dfrac{80}{1 - k}\$ and because k is a fraction we know that \$V_C\$ is greater than 80 volts.

But you could equally say it the other way: -

$$k\cdot V_C - V_C = 80$$

\$\color{blue}{\text{Below uses the inductor voltage as a positive reference}}\$

Rearranging we get: -

$$V_C(k-1) = 80$$

And this results in \$V_C = \dfrac{80}{k-1} = \dfrac{-80}{1-k}\$

In other words, the same voltage magnitude but an opposite sign (because in this version of the calculation we placed emphasis on the inductor voltage being our positive reference).

Comment: but the answer for that question is \$|V_C|=90\$,if i choose \$(V_L-V_C)=80\$,the \$|V_C|=70\$,if i choose \$(V_L-V_C)=-80\$,the \$|V_C|=90\$,so i think it should does matter,because if i choose the wrong one,\$80\$ or \$-80\$,the 
result will be wrong

Comment: No because the voltage across the inductor is 180 degrees out of phase with the voltage across the capacitor hence, it has a negative sign compared with the capacitor voltage so, realistically you should say \$(−V_L+V_C)=80\$ or.... \$|V_C|=90\$.

Comment: i want to ask ,you said " it has a negative sign compared with the capacitor voltage",but \$(V_L-V_C)=80\$ does have a negative sign compared with the capacitor voltage,then why should i write \$(-V_L+V_C)=80\$ instead of \$(V_L-V_C)=80\$?

Comment: The  reactive voltage should be \$I(X_L-X_C)=IX_L-IX_C=V_L-V_C=80.\$,so i think it should be right to write \$V_L-V_C=80\$.however,if i choose this,i will have a wrong answer

Comment: When I say +80 and \$+V_C\$, it's because I know that the 80 volts and the \$V_C\$ are in phase. I also know that \$V_L\$ is out of phase hence I give it a negative sign. So, if you write \$V_L - V_C = 80\$ that is only valid if \$V_L\$ is bigger than \$V_C\$. We are dealing with phasors and simple subtractive math only works when we give the correct sign. Of course, it's made easy by the fact that we know that \$V_C\$ is bigger than \$V_L\$ and this means that the 80 volts net signal is in phase with \$V_C\$. Because we know \$V_C\$ is bigger than \$V_L\$ we give \$V_L\$ a negative sign.

Comment: @XM551 are we done here now?

Comment: i have showed my thinking below,so i think i know where am i wrong now

Comment: @XM551 have you withdrawn your upvote and reversed it into a downvote - I got 12 points taken away this morning and that seems the most likely suggestion. After all, why would you accept your own answer (which is faulty) if my answer (being correct and a more complete explanation) had a clear upvote advantage. I suggest you are being silly, playing games, trying to justify your own (faulty) explanation or you are just being ungrateful of the help you get here. Either way, you should strongly consider what you have done.

Comment: it seems that you just be unhappy to lose some points,the reason i vote to my solution is that because it make sense to my self ,yours didn't answer my question

Comment: @XM551 You double down-voted my answer and that was just plain rude.

Comment: @why must i accept your answer?

Comment: Why did you double downvote my answer? @XM551

Comment: at first,i though your answer is really useful to me,so i give you a vote,after i read it carefully,i think  you didn't answer my real problem,so i take that vote  back to me